# Вывод только значений ассициативного массива

Tags: php

Как вывести только значения?

Например, есть массив

```
array('link' => 'Домой', 'href' => 'index.php')
```

В одну переменную, мне надо записать только **Домой**, а в другую **index.php**

У меня получается вывести ключ и значение, отдельно, я не знаю, как

```
$leftMenu = array(
    array('link' => 'Домой', 'href' => 'index.php'),
    array('link' => 'О нас', 'href' => 'about.php'),
    array('link' => 'Контакты', 'href' => 'contact.php'),
    array('link' => 'Таблица умножения', 'href' => 'table.php'),
    array('link' => 'Калькулятор', 'href' => 'calc.php')
);

foreach($leftMenu as $arr){
    foreach($arr as $link => $href){
        echo  $link . '<br>' . $href;
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас внутри **leftMenu** массивы, используя foreach вы получаете массив вида 
('link' => '', 'href'=>'').  Можете обратиться к его элементам внутри цикла подставив соответствующий ключ, например: $element['link']

```
$leftMenu = array(
    array('link' => 'Домой', 'href' => 'index.php'),
    array('link' => 'О нас', 'href' => 'about.php'),
    array('link' => 'Контакты', 'href' => 'contact.php'),
    array('link' => 'Таблица умножения', 'href' => 'table.php'),
    array('link' => 'Калькулятор', 'href' => 'calc.php')
);


foreach ($leftMenu as $element) {
    echo "<a href='{$element['href']}'>{$element['link']}</a><br>\n";
}
```

или вот так:

```
foreach ($leftMenu as $element) {
    echo "<a href='" . $element['href'] . "'>" . $element['link'] . "</a><br>\n";
}
```

Результат:

```
<a href='index.php'>Домой</a><br>
<a href='about.php'>О нас</a><br>
<a href='contact.php'>Контакты</a><br>
<a href='table.php'>Таблица умножения</a><br>
<a href='calc.php'>Калькулятор</a><br>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$leftMenu = array(
  '0' => ['link' => 'Домой', 'href' => 'index.php'],
  '1' => ['link' => 'О нас', 'href' => 'about.php'],
  '2' => ['link' => 'Контакты', 'href' => 'contact.php'],
  '3' => ['link' => 'Таблица умножения', 'href' => 'table.php'],
  '4' => ['link' => 'Калькулятор', 'href' => 'calc.php']
);
```

1:

```
foreach($leftMenu as $arr){
    $link_array[$arr[0]] = $arr[1];
}
```

2:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($leftMenu); $i++){
    $link_array[leftMenu[$i][0]]= $leftMenu[$i][1];
}
```

В обеих случаях получаете массив, где ключ - link, значение - href.